# Proof the theorem from linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, induction

x,y are **n**x**1** vectors of real numbers. Matrix **A** is a product of x and y'.

$$A=xy^T$$

Prove that for any x and y there exists $\lambda \in \Bbb R$ that meets equation $ A^{k}=\lambda^{k-1}A$, $k \in \Bbb N$.

**My idea** was to solve it through math induction.

For k=1 we have that $A=\lambda^0A$, which definitely holds.

The if we suppose that $A^n=\lambda^{n-1}A$ holds, then
$$AA^n=A\lambda^{n-1}A$$

How do we prove that $A\lambda^{n-1}=\lambda^{n}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can proceed as follows:
$$A^2=(xy^t)(xy^t)=x\underbrace{(y^tx)}_{\text{scalar, call it }c}y^t=cxy^t=cA.$$
Now you can get $$A^3=cA^2=c(cA)=c^2A,$$
and so on.

Comment: This is wery cool solution. Thank you